# Twitter User posts, retrieved with smappR and stored in JSON format, are not being read in to R

Tags: json, r, python-2.7, twitter, import

I am using the [smappR package](https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/smappR)to retrieve Twitter user posts, specifically the [getTimeline()](https://github.com/SMAPPNYU/smappR/blob/master/R/get-timeline.R) function.
However, the problem is that the [retrieved data, which has been stored in JSON format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6e1k9jjwys432b/Abgzik.json?dl=0) is not subsequently being read in as a JSON file by R.
The image below denotes the command and the corresponding error -
[image]

Was wondering if there is any other way we can read the files back into R for further processing?
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit 1 : Funnily enough, the file does not appear to be read in, even when I attempted the same in Python (2.7)
The Python Code is as follows -

```
with open('C:/Users/ABC/Downloads/twitter/profile/bethguido3.JSON') as data_file:    
   data = json.load(data_file)
```

The error that appeared is -
[image]

Comment: according to `http://jsonlint.com/`, your JSON file is not valid JSON...

Comment: Yes cory, you appear to be correct.
So, that implies that the fault lies with the file and not the code - some relief, howsoever little. :)
No worries, shall try and see where the error appears in the R package in that case.
Thanks for the information.